# Geometry Nodes Instances wont align to Face with Capture Attribute

Tags: geometry-nodes

For a project, I need to roll up a piece of Velcro. However, I cant seem to align the separate Velcro-Hooks to the Normal.

The mesh starts out as a edgeloop, which gets extruded to be used as the Base. This is also where i try to get my normal information from. This edgeloop is also rigged to bend.

Im using curves to establish an adaptive point grid on the base.

Last thing to do would be to align the hooks to the face, which i'm having problems with.

Why won't Capture Attribute work?
Is there an alternative way to align the hooks to the base?

[image: Node Set-up]
[image: Hooks not Alignet to Face] [image: Hooks not Alignet to Face Perpective]

[image]

Comment: to save our (!) time and in order to give you a precise and working solution, i would recommend providing a blend file. You want help by people, who do this for free in their spare time, so i would make it as easy as possible for them to answer...instead of letting the rebuild your node tree.

Comment: Of Course, sorry, first time.